# TimerElapsedEvent not working in UDP Agent in C#

Tags: c#, udp

My server is running continuously to receive data from Agent, but the Agent is getting closed after a single run.
Even my `timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);` is not working properly.

Agent Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace HeartBeatAgent
{
public class Agent
{

    static string clientdata = "IP1 Version 1";
    static UdpClient UdpAgent = new UdpClient();
    static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    static int ip = 127001;
    static int port = 6060;
    static IPEndPoint receivePoint;



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpAgent = new UdpClient(port);
        receivePoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(ip), port);
        Thread startClient = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startAgent));
        //Start the Thread
        startClient.Start();
    }

    public static void startAgent()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("This is Agent");

        //Send Data
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encode = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        string sendString = clientdata.ToString();
        byte[] sendMsg = encode.GetBytes(sendString);

        //Send to Server to corresponding port of server
        UdpAgent.Send(sendMsg, sendMsg.Length, "localhost", 6767);
        Console.WriteLine("Msg sent to server 4m agent");


        //Receive Data from Server
        byte[] recMsg = UdpAgent.Receive(ref receivePoint);
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding receive = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        //Split it up
        string[] temp = receive.GetString(recMsg).Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
        Console.WriteLine(temp[2] + temp[1] + temp[0]);

        **timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);**
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Start();

    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        startAgent();
    }

}
}
```

Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace HeartBeatServer
{
public class Server
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpClient UdpServer = new UdpClient(6767);

        int count = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                Dictionary<string, int> agentCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                Console.WriteLine("This is server");
                //Define a Receive point
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

                //Receive Data from Agent
                byte[] recData = UdpServer.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encode = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                //Split it up by space
                string[] temp = encode.GetString(recData).Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
                if (agentCount.ContainsKey(temp[0]))
                {
                    var coun = agentCount[temp[0]];

                    agentCount.Add(temp[0], coun++);
                    Console.WriteLine(coun);

                }
                else
                {
                    agentCount.Add(temp[0], count);
                    Console.WriteLine(temp[0], count);
                    //Re-send the Data to Agent
                    byte[] sendData = encode.GetBytes(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    UdpServer.Send(sendData, sendData.Length, "localhost", 6060);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reply Message Sent to Agent 4m Server");
                }


                Console.WriteLine(temp[0] + temp[1] + temp[2]);
                continue;
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

I need to send message continuously to server at time interval of 5-10 seconds. Able to achieve first time only. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: "is not working properly" is not sufficient detail. And can you clean up the code to just the necessary parts?

Comment: @GlenThomas yup, I cleared up the unwanted things. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: It looks like you adding a new Elapsed event handler each time you call the method. Try setting up the timer in the Main method, not in the startAgent method

Comment: @Glen Thomas could you please add the method in main and show me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a `Thread`, which calls a method and once that method ends the `Thread` will cease execution. Instead of using a thread, replace your Main method with this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UdpAgent = new UdpClient(port);
    receivePoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(ip), port); 
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Start();
}
```

and remove all timer related code from the startAgent method.